# datetime edit php to mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, html

I already connected my sql to database, but my isset post does not work

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:60px;margin-bottom:60px;">
 <div class="form-group pull-right">
  
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <p> Set Start DateTime<p>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="start"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1">SUBMIT</button>
  <br><br>
  <p> Set Deadline<p>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="end"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit2">SUBMIT</button>
  <br><br>
 </div>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
  $name = $_POST['start'];
  
  $sql = "UPDATE tbdeadline SET
   start = '$name'
   WHERE id = '1'
   ";
   
    if ($this->con->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo '<script>window.location.href="deadline.php"</script>';
   }
   else{
    echo 'error';
   }  
 }
?>
```

I want to update datetime in my "user" database whose table name is "start" and id = "1"

But my html is getting nowhere. It is not showing any error or anything else.

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to debug your code to find the issue. You can add print_r($_POST); die; before if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){ to check whether $_POST data coming or not.

Comment: And where is your form starting and ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think value from  is not send via $_POST. If I want to check if form is send I use

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit1" value="1" />
```

And check via

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the values for your Submit buttons.

You need to update your Submit buttons like below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1" value="start">SUBMIT</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit2" value="end">SUBMIT</button>
```

Also make sure your form method must be POST like below:

```
<form method="post">
```

If you still get isset error then you need to debug your $_POST to check whether form data is coming via form or not. Add below code before if condition to test:

```
print_r($_POST); die;
```

And use MySqli **Prepared Statements** for updating your query to make it more **Secure**.

Follow below link to learn more:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

The sql code is vulnerable to SQL injection - or it would be if it were not within single quotes rather than double. Using single quotes means that any PHP variable within must be escaped - easier to use double quotes and the values of the variables will be OK.

```
        <p> Set Start DateTime<p>
        <input type='datetime-local' name='start'><br><br>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>SUBMIT</button>
        <br><br>

        <p> Set Deadline<p>
        <input type='datetime-local' name='end'><br><br>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>SUBMIT</button>
        <br><br>

    </div>
</div>

<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['start'],$_POST['end'] )){

        $name = $_POST['start'];
        $end = $_POST['end'];

        /* This is vulnerable to SQL injection !! */
        /* use double quotes around sql or better mysqli/PDO and  `prepared statements` */
        $sql = "UPDATE tbdeadline SET start = '$name' WHERE id = '1'";

        if( $this->con->query($sql) === TRUE ){
            echo '<script>window.location.href='deadline.php'</script>';
        } else{
            echo 'error';
        }       
    }
?>
```